# Ugly looking selection in Visual Studio 2012 text editor

Tags: text-editor, visual-studio-2012, appearance

I've started to use Visual Studio 2012 and there is one feature that really upsets me: the way the selection in text editor looks. For some reason it looks differently for variables and all other text. The same is right for the break-point high-lighting:

[image: Visual Studio 2012 selection]

Is there a setting to make the selection and break-pointed line appear uniform as in all previous versions of VS and all other editors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no setting for this, but why your selection looks ugly is because you set a background color for given (identifier) types. In `Tools*Options*Environment*Fonts and Colors` select `Identifiers` and set `Item Background` to `Default`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot! Even if I didn't set background color, it was set just after the installation. Maybe it has migrated from somewhere, don't know.